# Using Smarty, is it possible to call a method on the return value of a method?

Tags: php, smarty

I have the Smarty code

```
{$obj->foo()->bar()}
```

and Smarty complains about 'unrecognized tag' in the expression. If I change it to just

```
{$obj->foo()}
```

it doesn't complain, so I assume the problem is with the fact that I'm calling a method on the result of a method. Is this a limitation of Smarty's parser, or am I missing something else here?

I know I can work around this with `{assign}`, I just wanted to know if I'd understood the extent of the limitations correctly.

Comment: As much as I remember (my Smarty times ended about 5 years ago?) I was using `{assign}` for this. There might be a more elegant solution, but I think I searched around back then, and this was all I could find. Good luck!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Are you using Smarty2 or Smarty3?

Smarty2 will require you to use `{assign}` after the first method.  It will also have problems if you pass more than one argument to a method.

Smarty3 has a completely rewritten parser and you can do exactly what you want.  You also no longer need `{assign}`, as you can simply do `{$new_var = "Anything"}`.

Here's a test in Smarty3:

Our classes

```
class Foo {
    function boo() {
        return new Boo(); 
    }
}

class Boo {
    function woo() {
        return "woo!";
    }
}
```

Template variables assigned

```
$foo = new Foo();
$tpl->assign('foo', $foo);
```

Template

```
{$foo->boo()->woo()}
```

Browser Output

```
woo!
```

Comment: I was using Smarty 2, but it's good to know that Smarty 3 fixes it. I may update when it's got a final release.